# How to obtain Microsoft code signing certificate for signing supplementary material for scientific article?

Tags: supporting-information

Our research results (mathematical models) can be supplemented by rather convincible and impressive visualizations of both scientific concept and experimental data. We produced this demonstration material in the form of executable files that could be downloaded from our website to run locally. The material is written in real programming language, not a wrapper around some third party tool. They were initially written as Java applets, now we converted them into stand alone executables.

To look somewhat "correct", the executable to share in these days must be digitally signed ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx) is the full explanation). Unsigned Java applets cannot run at all in these days. Unsigned MSI installers still run, but display various nasty warnings that may scare of half of the audience.

Our research group is not a company like AG or GMBH, so it is not included into databases where that allow true companies to be verified and obtain certificates rather easily. We really cannot register a commercial company just to sign our demonstration material.

This only leaves an option for the researcher to obtain the certificate as individual. While theoretically the procedure exists and appears simple (just present a few documents to the Notary), in reality we failed multiple times because for the certificate issuer such a researcher is a "strange person from the street" with not enough trust to issue this electronic document. One of the main they argumentation was that my citizenship does not match the country of the residence (that is, I would say, very common between scientists that move between positions over the world). Also they said they do not like how the Notary has done his job with document signing, while it was an official Notary, and I am not sure if any other could do better. I am in German speaking country, the instructions were in English and the Notary even said he is unable legally follow them. Finally they asked me to hire a true lawyer rather than just a notary, and at this point we were forced to withdraw.

After the long pause I have applied for the certificate for the second time, but to avoid wasted time and useless expenses with the Notary, tried to discuss these two problems with the provider in advance. As a result, my application has been immediately cancelled. Rather tough approach, I would say.

How is this problem supposed to be solved? Is there any institution or process that would allow researcher to sign his code for online sharing, using his academic identity as part of the trust? Random providers offering to issue such certificates rather cheaply basically do not want to go into any talks if you are not a commercial company.

Comment: I'd recommend contacting Microsoft. I don't know how it works for Microsoft; for a corresponding certificate from Apple you must be a registered developer ($99 a year) and have a company, which in the UK would cost you £12 to register and £15 per year; this seems to be much, much more expensive in Germany, so there might be another way. That's why I recommend contacting them. And they _might_ accept some academic institution.

Comment: I would not expect research code to be signed.

Comment: I agree with @AnonymousPhysicist - anyone who wants to run your software will 1. not care about whether or not it's signed, and 2. likely be familiar with how to run unsigned applications. I wouldn't worry about it, you're just going to complicate the development-release cycle.